# SingleTickerProviderStateMixin and custom mixin

Tags: flutter, dart, mixins

I'm a bit of a newb with Flutter and Dart, and Google couldn't help me with this question.

Say I have this:

`class _MapPageState extends BaseState<MapPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`

I want to add another mixin (BasePage) on top of this that contains a reusable appbar, drawer, etc. The layout is described in [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/mixins-and-base-classes-a-recipe-for-success-in-flutter-bc3fbb5da670).

I know this is not possible, and my IDE throws an error that tells me to integrate them, but I do not know how. Is there a solution? I need `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` because it is required by an AnimationController I am using.

Here is the custom mixin code, if needed:

```
abstract class Base extends StatefulWidget {
  Base({Key key}) : super(key: key);
}

abstract class BaseState<Page extends Base> extends State<Page> {
  String screenName();
}

mixin BasePage<Page extends Base> on BaseState<Page> {

  MapFunctions functions = MapFunctions();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Guidey'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        drawer: Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            canvasColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)
          ),
          child: Drawer(
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40.0, 10.0, 40.0, 10.0),
              children: <Widget>[
                DrawerHeader(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 35, 0, 0),
                    child: Text('Navigation', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white))
                  )
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Profile', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.white70),
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Map', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.drive_eta, color: Colors.white70),
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('My Location', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.store, color: Colors.white70),
                  onTap: (){
                  },
                )
              ],
            )
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

  Widget body();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out I was thinking too big, combining mixins can be done with a simple comma.

`... with SingleTickProviderMixin, BasePageMixin`